# Python check if list only contains either empty elements or whitespace

Tags: python, list, boolean, whitespace

I would like to check if a list only contains either empty elements or whitespace, something like:

```
l = ['','   ','\n']
if all(whitespace or empty for element in l):
    return True
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well your *whitespace* is simply `str.isspace(..)` so:

```
if all('' == s or s.isspace() for s in l):
    return True
```

Comment: I have read elsewhere that all() is very quick, but maybe they were wrong D:

Comment: Also I guess I have to take into account that it has to check two scenarios

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is probably to use `str.strip()`, which will return the empty string if the source string contains only whitespace. The empty string is falsey.

```
if not any(s.strip() for s in l): return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if not any(s.strip() for s in l):
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different answer using all instead of any:

```
if  all([not x.strip() for x in l]):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to achieve needed result, but using str.split():

```
if all(not x.split() for x in l):
   return True
```