# ArgumentParser - add list with default=None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to add a list of arguments to my program with the argument parser. it works fine if the arguments are set, but if the arguments are 'empty' the list set with nothing.

My problem is, that the script is called by a jenkins, so the variable of arguents are set automatically to a list or to nothing.

the call from jenkins looks like:

```
test.py -list1=1,2,3 -list2=
```

the results are:

```
list1 is = [1,2,3]
```

and

```
list2 is = ['']
```

My ArgumentParser-Code:

```
parser.add_argument('-list1', nargs='*', default=None, help="list")
parser.add_argument('-list2', nargs='*', default=None, help="list")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I need a way to set list2 to None, so i can check if list2 is set or not.

Comment: You *did* provide a value for list2; you provided the empty string. `default` is only used if `--list2` is entirely absent from the command line. Also, the list you get for `args.list1` is the single-element list `['1,2,3']`, not a 3-element list like `[1,2,3]` or `['1', '2', '3']`. `nargs='*'` indicates that you can specify multiple arguments for  `--list1`, not that it will parse a comma-separated argument for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `list2` to see if it's got anything inside of it - I'm assuming from the example you posted that, if there's no arguments passed, the only thing in it will be an empty string. If you call `str.strip()` on an empty / whitespace only string, it returns the empty string, which is falsey.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261784/7431860): `if not any(s.strip for s in list2): list2 = None`